# Animate SVG inside SVG in Snap.js

Tags: javascript, css, svg, css-animations, snap.svg

I can't animate SVG loaded into SVG container.
I have `<svg id="roulette"></svg>` and loading SVG with Snap.js into it (that have id #Layer_1). And CSS animation not applicable to loaded SVG #Layer_1

```
#Layer_1 {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-animation: whirl 2s linear infinite;
    animation: whirl 2s linear infinite;
}
```

But if I animate the whole SVG container #Roulette - it's work. But me need to animate just a one loaded SVG with id #Layer_1.

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/X3WtYCVKgTtmYhBIN9lH?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to target the id which is inside the html file, not the one inside the svg file.

#### CSS

```
.block {
    position: relative;
}

#roulette {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    animation: whirl 2s linear infinite;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="block">
  <svg id="roulette"></svg>
</div>
```

If you want to animate your svg more precisely, add class to `<g>` tags inside the svg file and play with them.